# Drawing samples from a joint distribution defined by limits?

Tags: sampling, linear-model, linear, uniform-distribution, accept-reject

Assume that I want to efficiently draw samples from a (for simplicity bivariate) joint distribution $p(x,y)$, with $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}$. I don't have a closed-form expression for $p(x,y)$, but I can prescribe a number of features and limits that should describe it fully. As a concrete example, consider these limits and properties:

- Variable limit 1: $-25 \leq x \leq 25$
- Variable limit 2: $-25 \leq y \leq 25$
- Variable limit 3: $-5 \leq x + y \leq 5$
- Joint uniformity: $p(x,y) = \text{constant}$ for all $(x,y)$ in the support above

One way to sample this distribution would be via [rejection sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling), i.e., just drawing independent samples $x \sim \mathcal{U}[-25,25]$ and $y \sim \mathcal{U}[-25,25]$ and then rejecting all samples that violate variable limit 3. However, depending on the narrow nature of limit 3 (consider for instance the limiting case $0 \leq x + y \leq 0$), this might reject virtually all samples.

Is there a more efficient way to sample from a distribution like this?

Comment: I do not understand why you state that there is no closed form expression for $p(x,y)$ since the distribution is uniform over the support. Hence, the density is the indicator function of the support divided by the surface of the support. Simulation can be done by Gibbs sampling.

Comment: @Xi'an: Thank you for the suggestion! Gibbs sampling is a great idea I didn't think of. Ultimately, I opted for a different approach due to a few corner cases in which Gibbs sampling would fail (e.g., if the support is an arbitrarily rotated 2D line in 3D space), which also circumvents the need to discard a burn-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since found a solution that works quite efficiently, and wanted to briefly state it here for anyone else who might end up with a similar question. The solution I found works, but ended up being a bit more complex than I initially anticipated.

1. As in [linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming), find the polytope vertices defined by the inequalities above.
2. Triangulate the polytope
3. Calculate the volume of each resulting simplex
4. Select one simplex at random, with each simplex weighted by its percentage contribution to the overall polytope volume.
5. Draw a uniform sample from a uniform Dirichlet distribution of the same dimension as the simplex and polytope
6. Transform the barycentric coordinates into cartesian coordinates.